# System Updated to 3.13 Kernel that won't boot

Tags: boot, kernel

Recently, I got a message that told me automatic updates to my hardware would end 8/07 and decided to update my system to the latest kernel version 3.13. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on some fairly old hardware. Upon loading the kernel panics immediately, however, GRUB is giving me the option to boot to a previous kernel (3.5-54) which was working fine. I'm looking to update to 14.04 eventually, but would like to boot to the old kernel by default. Any suggestions?

Comment: The kernel stack updates like the ones you are taking advantage of are providing extra support for newer hardware not yet supported by kernel 3.2. I don't know that you can use an older kernel in 14.04 see here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack.